# how to apply colour to a single barplot in R?

Tags: r

This is my barchart

[image]

I want to show "2014" plot in pink colour.I tried using

```
>barplot(seq(1:12), col=topo.colors(12))
```

All the plots are coloured,i want only "2014" plot to be coloured in pink & the remaining plots should remain the same color.Please guide me with the package too.

Comment: `barplot(sample(1:15, 5), names.arg = c(2010:2014), col=c(rep("grey",4), "pink"))`